# How to inject a configuration file into an openshift docker build (not a pod)

Tags: docker, openshift

Before the docker build starts I am producing a configuration file which contains a lot of environment specific configuration. I don't want it in my repository because it changes frequently.

Openshift recommends for artifacts needed during a docker build to downloaded them directly from the container. [Here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-external-artifacts). Since they are mostly unique for each deployment and immutably stored on the container I would like to avoid having to first push the config file to a artifact repo just to download it again from the container.

Additionally they may have sensitive data. (although that should be easy to inject via environment variables)

Is there a different way to pass small configuration files (<10KB) to the openshift docker build context?

Update: I only use openshift in this case as a docker builder and push the target to an external repository. From there the container is picked up for deployment.
(The situation is we are in the middle of a migration where the target architecture is not yet defined, but some specific parts must be already used. Like Openshift for cicd)

Answer (score 1):

Is the configuration affecting the build, or just the deployment?

If it is just the deployment, use config maps or secrets. These can be used as source for setting environment variables, or mounted as files in the container for the deployment.

Comment: It's the configuration for the running deployment. Yes I've been considering secret files. But that would be overkill since I'd like to only have these secrets to exist during the build. I would create a secret, somehow copy it into the container and then delete it again. So I would have to make sure the lifecycle is stable for more temporary resources. So that nothing stays by accident when a build fails or something else goes wrong.
The same would be true for config maps. The actual configuration resides in a different parameter store and so they would have to be created for every build.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You said it is the configuration for the running deployment, but then say you only want it to exist during the build. That doesn't quite make sense as it would have to be preserved in the image to be available for the deployment. Can you explain in more detail what the configuration is for? If for a deployment, the choices are environment variables, config maps and secrets. These aren't overkill, it is the methods you are provided to use and is normal to use them.

Comment: Okay, noticed your clarification in question. Use a build secret and have the steps for the build copy the file into different location in the image. If this is secret information, it means you are keeping it in the image, which usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: Run ``oc explain bc.spec.source.secrets`` to see details on build secrets.